# Any neat way to show this integral tends to zero as $N$ blows up?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Provided that $m(t)$ is an integrable real-valued function on $[-\pi,\pi]$, $N$ a positive integer, how to prove
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}m(t)\sin Nt \,\mathrm dt\to0\quad\text{as}\quad N\to\infty$$ ?

I tried $|\int fg|\le\int |fg|\le \sup|f|\int|g|$, but RHS is too weak as an upper bound, since integrating $|\sin Nt|$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ will yield no infinitesimal amount w.r.t. $N$.

Although intuitively it seems that the values of $\sin Nt$ are distributed more and more "uniformly" between $-1$ and $1$ when $N$ tends to infinity, which makes Riemann sum seem like a promising tool, but I'm still expecting for a more elegant way than this from-scratch one.

Can you help me? Any direct answer or hint (but not too obscure, please) will be appreciated sincerely. Best regards!

---

PS: This appears in the last inequality in Theorem 8.14, Baby Rudin which proves the pointwise convergence of trigonometric Fourier series (I have modified a little, though). Thus we are not supposed to use the Fourier series tool.

---

PPS: The original version in Baby Rudin Chapter 8, page 190 (third editon, McGraw Hill) is as follows, in which $f$ is assumed to be an *integrable* complex-valued function on $[-\pi,\pi]$, $s_N(f;x)$ being the $N-$th partial sum of the (trig) Fourier series of $f$:

> **Theorem 8.14** $\quad$ If, for some $x$, there are constants $\delta>0$ and $M<\infty$ s.t.
>   $$|f(x+t)-f(x)|\le M|t|$$
>   for all $t\in(-\delta,\delta)$ then
>   $$\lim_{N\to\infty}s_N(f;x)=f(x)$$
>   **Proof** $\quad$ Define
>   $$g(t)=\frac{f(x-t)-f(x)}{\sin(\frac{t}2)}$$
>   At the end of the proof, the author showed that
>   $$|s_N(f;x)-f(x)|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[g(t)\cos\frac{t}2]\sin Nt\,\mathrm dt+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[g(t)\sin\frac{t}2]\cos Nt\,\mathrm dt $$

And he claimed that since $g(t)\cos\frac{t}2$ and $g(t)\sin\frac{t}2$ are both bounded, the last two integrals thus tend to $0$ as $N\to\infty$.

But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.  There are proofs in many places on the Internet, but I don't know if there is any clever argument of the sort wanted in the question.

The lemma needs some condition on $m(t)$, such as integrable or continuous.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah they are indeed some conditions on it, I'll add it in my edit.

Comment: Bessel's inequality seems to work.. which Rudin introduced before dealing with the convergence issue of Fourier series.